# Trouble with naming conventions in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions

I've always hated the scaffolding in MVC, so I decided to design my own Models, Views and Controllers. I have a model called CEmployee, a controller called ManageCEmployeeController, and a folder within the View folder called ManageCEmployee. The problem is that when I try to add a model inside the Index.cshtml file (which is in the previously mentioned folder) I get a few errors, which you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAtHA.jpg

According to some stuff I've found online, I've fulfilled all the conventions.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your header tag I am going to say that you are wanting to list some data from your datasource. **@using EmployeesTracking.Models** is fine but you are going to provide a list to this view. You need to let the view know you are fixing to throw a list of data at it by declaring

```
     @using System.Collections.Generic;
     @using EmployeesTracking.Models;
     @model IEnumerable<CEmployees>;
```

IEnumerable is a list of data. This tells the view that the controller has already looked at your model class **CEmployee** and has a list of data ready to display.

Now I know you said you didn't like the scaffolding, but it is a great way to get started and you can simply take out what you don't want real easy.

Comment: Huh? How did you _infer_ all of that from the post? There is no problem with `@model CEmployee` based on what is in the question or image.

Comment: When you use scaffolding and it builds a "list" view it uses a heading of <h2>List <h2>. In his code you will see this at the bottom. If you are going to render a list it has to be an IEnumerable <>, ICollection <>, or IList <>. I use scaffolding a lot so I noticed this right away. Also he is using index.chtml as the view name which is also the standard name scaffolding gives the "list" view. It requires an IEnumurable collection from the model. I am assuming he is using code he is familiar with when he did use scaffolding

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon (`;`) from your `@model` declaration:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using EmployeesTracking.Models;

//No semi-colon terminator needed...
@model CEmployee
```

Hth...